# WMQ Message Group Parallel execution

Tags: ibm-mq

I have a requirement to store large number of messages in a queue when the consumer is down and process them sequentially when the consumer is restored. I want to group together logically related messages and execute all the groups in parallel.

Eg: Consider the queue below with 3 groups A, B, C. I have assigned seqnum to contents and unique groupIds to the groups correctly.
Queue-1
A1,A2,A3-last,B1,B2-last,C1,C2,c3,C4-last

1. Is it possible to Fetch A1, B1, C1 in parallel?
2. Also currently the consumer is fetching A1, A2 and A3 correctly in order. But it is not able to fetch any content from group B or C. What might be wrong?

Any suggestions will deeply help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First read this [page](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_7.0.1/com.ibm.mq.csqzal.doc/fg12930_.htm) from the MQ Knowledge.

I converted the pseudo code (from the web page above) to MQ classes for Java and changed it from a browse to a destructive get.

Also, I prefer to do each group of messages under a syncpoint (assuming a reasonable sized groups).

```
MQGetMessageOptions gmo = new MQGetMessageOptions();
MQMessage rcvMsg = new MQMessage();

/* Get the first message in a group, or a message not in a group */
gmo.Options = CMQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG | CMQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | CMQC.MQGMO_ALL_MSGS_AVAILABLE | CMQC.MQGMO_WAIT | CMQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
gmo.MatchOptions = CMQC.MQMO_MATCH_MSG_SEQ_NUMBER;
rcvMsg.messageSequenceNumber = 1;
rcvMsg.groupId = CMQC.MQGI_NONE;
inQ.get(rcvMsg, gmo);

/* Examine first or only message */
 ...

gmo.Options = CMQC.MQGMO_COMPLETE_MSG | CMQC.MQGMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | CMQC.MQGMO_SYNCPOINT;
do while ((rcvMsg.messageFlags & CMQC.MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP) == CMQC.MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP)
{
    rcvMsg.clearMessage();
    inQ.get(rcvMsg, gmo);
   /* Examine each remaining message in the group */
   ...
}
qMgr.commit();
```

There are a couple of coding things that must be done: (1) using the right options and (2) clearing the groupId field before you get the next group.

Comment: This answers point 2. of his question, but not point 1. where he asks about getting the messages A1, B1 and C1 in parallel. It's a good answer so I don't want to create another one - could you update to cover point 1. as well?

Comment: The answer to point 1 is to start the class as a thread.  Hence, you start as many threads as is needed.

Comment: :-) Thanks Roger! I meant could you update your answer text to include it